Pull data from a specific column in SpatVector in terra package
Does anyone know how to specify a column within a SpatVector in the terra package? I am running a for loop and along with the value being calculated I need it to pull the value from an ID column in the SpatVector and put it in the dataframe with the results.
When reading in a spatial polygon with rgdal readOGR function I could specify a column with camera@data[i,"Cat_ID"] but with the terra package it gives me the following error
Error:  no slot of name "data" for this object of class "SpatVector"
So all I'm asking is what I should use instead of "camera@data" for a SpatVector in the package terra. I have tried camera@names and camera$names but neither doesn't work.
Here is the info for the "camera" SpatVector if that is helpful. I am not including example data because it doesn't seem necessary for this question.


You should be looking at str(camera).

Welcome to SO! When asking an R question, please always include a minimal, self-contained, reproducible example (see my answer and most Q&A on this site). Include R output as-is, do not include screenshots except when asking about plotting.

You can use the $ or [[ operators (similar to what you can do with a data.frame
library(terra)
f <- system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra")
v <- vect(f)
v
# class       : SpatVector 
# geometry    : polygons 
# dimensions  : 12, 6  (geometries, attributes)
# extent      : 5.74414, 6.528252, 49.44781, 50.18162  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# source      : lux.shp
# coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
# names       :  ID_1   NAME_1  ID_2   NAME_2  AREA   POP
# type        : <num>    <chr> <num>    <chr> <num> <int>
# values      :     1 Diekirch     1 Clervaux   312 18081
#                   1 Diekirch     2 Diekirch   218 32543
#                   1 Diekirch     3  Redange   259 18664

v$NAME_2
# [1] "Clervaux"         "Diekirch"         "Redange"          "Vianden"         
# [5] "Wiltz"            "Echternach"       "Remich"           "Grevenmacher"    
# [9] "Capellen"         "Esch-sur-Alzette" "Luxembourg"       "Mersch"          

v[["NAME_2"]]
#             NAME_2
#1          Clervaux
#2          Diekirch
#3           Redange
#4           Vianden
#5             Wiltz
#6        Echternach
#7            Remich
#8      Grevenmacher
#9          Capellen
#10 Esch-sur-Alzette
#11       Luxembourg
#12           Mersch



This was helpful thanks. Turns out I need to treat it like a vector not a matrix. camera$Cat_ID[i] worked
